# Who is the man in the picture

Tags: logical-deduction

Alex is looking at a picture of a man and states, "Brothers and sisters have I none, but that man's father is my father's son."

> Who is the man in the picture?

Comment: I am pretty sure, this is a duplicate (has already been asked here). But I cannot find the original by searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alex is showing the picture of:

> His Son.

Comment: +1 Late again. My answer was too short and didn't get through. :( Anyway it turned out wrong so I deleted it. :)

Comment: As generally it goes ... Alex is the name of a _male_ person :-)

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Alexandra (the female version) which is also shortened to Alex is a really popular name

Comment: @IPlant In such a case **Her Son** is also a valid answer : - P

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay Nope. Alex says "Father's son". Thus, Alex has to be a male.

Comment: @Sid What if Alex(a female)'s husband is in the picture?

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay How would Alex's husband's father be the same as Alex's father? You are probably confusing "father" and "father-in-law"

Comment: @Sid, got it, where I went wrong. **Alex's son** could have been a best fit.